# onClick "input text box" open textarea and click on document it should closed

Tags: jquery

## 1 )

On click to input text 
![Input box][1]

## 2)

after this text area will open

![text area][2]

3) This is my document where i want to click outside of this text area it should be hide.

![my whole document ][3]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read carefully the FAQ area before posting a question. http://stackoverflow.com/faq This question makes little sense.

Comment: Please specify the person name who should do your homework :). This is question answers forum. Not a homework forum.Ask the question in a pleasing way

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this what you're looking to do..

```
$('input[type="text"]').bind('focus', function(){
    $('textarea').show();
}).bind('blur', function(){
    $('textarea').hide();
});
```